# Why do I need to set content-type to html in this Java Servlet?

Tags: html, servlets, xhtml, content-type

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head><title>only for test</title></head><body>Hello, world!html version</body></html>");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

If I set the content-type to `xhtml`, then the web-browser would automatically open the save-file dialog. Why would this happen?

Comment: You're another victim of the XHTML overhype. Put your mouse on top of `[xhtml]` tag you placed on the question until a popbox shows up, and then click therein the *"info"* link, and get enlightenend. Just use `text/html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that the right content-type for xhtml is not `xhtml` or `text/xhtml`, but `application/xhtml+xml`.

Anyway, you'll need to check whether the user agent can actually accept this content-type by examining the `Accept` HTTP request header. According to [the W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#media-types):

1. If the Accept header explicitly contains `application/xhtml+xml` (with either no "q" parameter or a positive "q" value) deliver the document using that media type.
2. If the Accept header explicitly contains `text/html` (with either no "q" parameter or a positive "q" value) deliver the document using that media type.
3. If the accept header contains "*/*" (a convention some user agents use to indicate that they will accept anything), deliver the document using `text/html`.

Answer (score 1):

text/xhtml is not a valid content type so your browser won't know how to render it properly.

For XHTML 1.0 the content type is supposed to be text/html http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines  (See point A.9)

Edit:

This is a better link that specifically discusses XHTML and its various allowed Content-Type's

http://www.w3.org/International/articles/serving-xhtml/

Comment: Point A.9 refers to character encodings. See section 3 for recommended media types (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#media-types).

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. When you say *set the content-type to `xhtml`* you mean literally `xhtml` or `text/xhtml` — in which case the problem is that the content type for XHTML is `application/xhtml+xml`
2. You are using Internet Explorer 8 or lower, which doesn't support XHTML. Support is being added in IE9 and is only available if you are using the beta.

Answer (score 0):

Its method that take string parameter and returns nothing.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

here "text" is type and html is subtype.

`setContentType()` method sets the content type of "response being delivered", when response is not yet sent over.
You can say for css:

```
response.setContentType("text/css");
```

Answer (score -2):

Isn't it basic browser feature?

If browser know the file format(like html or xml or text ..) it will display the contents directly on the browser

Otherwise, it tries to save it or open with other application

Comment: The browser "knows" that based on the `Content-Type` header. That's where this question is all about :)